# C++: Not actually reading from binary file

Tags: c++, binary

I know this kind of question has been frequently asked but no matter what example I follow I can't seem to get the expected results. I want to read integers from a binary file and store them in a vector. I have the code below.

```
std::ifstream infile;
infile.open(fileName.c_str(), std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);

infile.seekg(0, infile.end);
long size = infile.tellg();

std::vector<int> input(size/sizeof(int), 0);

// Option 1
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&input[0]), size);

// Option 2
infile.read((char*)&input[0], size);

infile.close();
```

I have tried both options when reading, but when I'm printing the contents of the vector, all elements are zero.

Comment: You never checked if your file was open or read successfully

Comment: After seeking to the end, you are at EOF.  seek to beginning before you start reading.

Comment: Hey stark. Thanks for the suggestion. It is actually reading data now, but the data are completely bogus.

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in your code that wrote the file as well.

Comment: BTW, don't read binary into `std::vector`, unless you know the underlying structure.  IMHO, better to read into a temporary integer, then put the integer into the vector.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
// Option 1
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&input[0]), sizeof(int);
```

[std::istream::read()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)
[std::istream::tellg()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)

You need to pass the size of the piece of data you want to read, not the size of the entire file. As mentioned in the comments, you also need to reset the pointer to the beginning of the file after you determine the size.

If you're using a newer C++ (C++11), the conversion of the filename to a C-string is not necessary. If you have C++17, it may be worth learning the `<filesystem>` library.

If you're wanting to read many ints, put the read in a loop.